# Cannot upload object of size more than 2147483647 bytes using swift python API

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, openstack-swift

## Connect to the object storage

```
      user1_connection = swiftclient.client.Connection(user=sl_user,key=user_key,authurl=endpoint_url)
```

## Upload object to container

```
   with open(object_path, 'r') as temp:
     user2_connection.put_object(container_name, object_name, contents= temp.read(),content_type=content_type)
```

Upload throws an error for object size of 3GB.

ERROR: OverflowError: string longer than 2147483647 bytes

## Updated

For test purpose, I was trying to upload 17mb of file in multiparts.

## Code

```
     file_size = os.path.getsize(object_path)
                    block_size = 5242880
                    chunk_size = block_size
                    chunks = math.ceil(file_size / float(chunk_size))
                    chunks = int (chunks)
                    print("Reading in file")
                    file = open(object_path, 'rb')
                    for i in range(0, chunks):
                              data = file.read(chunk_size)
                              print("Uploading part {} of {}".format(i + 1, chunks))
                              chunk_name = "chunk-{0:0>5}".format(i)
                              user2_connection.put_object(container_name, object_name+'/'+chunk_name,
                                            contents= data,
                                            content_type=content_type)
                    headers = {
                    "X-Object-Manifest": container_name+"/"+object_name+"/",
                    }
                    user2_connection.post_object(container_name,object_name,headers=headers)
```

swift list YUGOTEST1 --lh

```
       0 2017-07-25 04:14:29 application/octet-stream programs/ProductionObjectStorage20150828.log
    5.0M 2017-07-25 04:14:24 application/octet-stream programs/ProductionObjectStorage20150828.log/chunk-00000
    5.0M 2017-07-25 04:14:25 application/octet-stream programs/ProductionObjectStorage20150828.log/chunk-00001
    5.0M 2017-07-25 04:14:27 application/octet-stream programs/ProductionObjectStorage20150828.log/chunk-00002
    1.5M 2017-07-25 04:14:28 application/octet-stream programs/ProductionObjectStorage20150828.log/chunk-00003
     16M
```

swift stat YUGOTEST1 programs/ProductionObjectStorage20150828.log

```
           Account: AUTH_abcd7
         Container: YUGOTEST1
            Object: programs/ProductionObjectStorage20150828.log
      Content Type: application/octet-stream
    Content Length: 17348182
     Last Modified: Tue, 25 Jul 2017 04:14:30 GMT
              ETag: "afbd3bc65dbcd"
          Manifest: YUGOTEST1/programs/ProductionObjectStorage20150828.log/
     Accept-Ranges: bytes
       X-Timestamp: 1500956069.09158
        X-Trans-Id: tx0bcd
```

swift download YUGOTEST1 programs/ProductionObjectStorage20150828.log

```
    Error downloading object 'YUGOTEST1/programs/ProductionObjectStorage20150828.log': [Errno 21] Is a directory: u'programs/ProductionObjectStorage20150828.log'
```

Comment: You can try using Segmentation which breaks up a large file into smaller portions, thus allowing you to upload very large files. A manifest file is created so you can download the file all at once. You can find more info here: https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/overview_large_objects.html#using-swift

Comment: Could you share any example for python API?

Answer (score 0):

Try streaming upload, i.e pass your file object to data kwargs instead reading the file and passing it

so for your example, it will be as follows:

```
with open(object_path, 'r') as temp:
         user2_connection.put_object(container_name, object_name, contents=temp,content_type=content_type)
```

Reference: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads